# Blank header in odd pages, toptesi class

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I'm using the documentclass `toptesi` by Claudio Beccari for writing my master thesis.
This class automatically produce a header, with chapter title on the even pages and section title on the odd pages.
My problem is that when I have to write the appendix I only have a title for the chapter and not for the section (no section needed), and so the result is an empty header. Is it a typo or is it right?
If is not right, what solution can I use to fix it? Like printing the same title (or none) on both pages.
Here is an example of the code:

```
\documentclass[ 12pt, twoside]{toptesi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\english
\indici
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-13]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide link where this `toptesi` class is available?

Comment: here it is the [link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/toptesi)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `toptesi` is available on both TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg: I have already detected it there, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\chaptermark` in the `appendices` environment to set both the left and the right marks.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{toptesi}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\english
\indici
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\kant
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\thechapter\ -- #1}{\thechapter\ -- #1}%
}

\chapter{First appendix}
\kant
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I used `kantlipsum` because with English hyphenation it is better than `lipsum`.

Comment: Marked as accepted solution. Anyway I am able to compile the code with `lipsum` while using `toptesi`. Not big deal, just saying.

Comment: @maximator I didn't realize I was using an old version of `toptesi`.